# Use of "dispatch_queue_t" for parsing image in a custom table cell not working perfectly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

This is my 1st post in StackOver flow and my English is not good. I am a beginner in iOS, so i am slow little bit.
Actually i want to parse 5 of my data (including Image) from URL. I use custom tableView cell for it. My plain text are showing in custom cell (in lable) clearly but images are not. That's why i use "dispatch_queue_t" for loading the image in a particular ImageView. When i run the simulator the images showing up (Logo & BackGround) one after another row perfectly, but the problem happen when i reset the simulator. After reset it, one image (the last one in queue) load in every cell (total 5). I call my "parsingLoad" method in "viewDidLoad", so that it only load, once at the time of loading viewController. Can any one told me what did i wrong?

Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FairListCustomCell";

FairListCustomCell *cell = (FairListCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *topLabelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FairListCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLabelObject)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell =  (FairListCustomCell*) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

currentFair = [fairs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.fairNameLabel.text =currentFair.FairName;
cell.fairLocationLabel.text =currentFair.FairLocation;
cell.bookmarkImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favorite.png"];
cell.bookmarkImageView.tag=indexPath.row;

dispatch_queue_t imageQueueFairLogo = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(imageQueueFairLogo, ^
{
    dispatch_retain(imageQueueFairLogo);
    UIImage *imageFairLogo = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentFair FairLogo]]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        cell.fairLogoImageView.image = imageFairLogo;
        #if NEEDS_DISPATCH_RETAIN_RELEASE
            dispatch_release(imageQueueFairLogo);
        #endif
    });
});

dispatch_queue_t imageQueueFairCellBackGround = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(imageQueueFairCellBackGround, ^
{
    dispatch_retain(imageQueueFairCellBackGround);
    UIImage *imageFairCellBackGround = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentFair FairCellBackGround]]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        cell.fairCellBackGround.image = imageFairCellBackGround;
        #if NEEDS_DISPATCH_RETAIN_RELEASE
        dispatch_release(imageQueueFairCellBackGround);
        #endif
    });
});

return cell;
```

}

I also try with another tow ways.
1st :- using "global_queue" for both of Images (here as a sample just put one), 
like this :

```
imageQueueFairCellBackGround = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(imageQueueFairCellBackGround, ^
{
    dispatch_retain(imageQueueFairCellBackGround);
    UIImage *imageFairCellBackGround = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentFair FairCellBackGround]]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        cell.fairCellBackGround.image = imageFairCellBackGround;
        #if NEEDS_DISPATCH_RETAIN_RELEASE
        dispatch_release(imageQueueFairCellBackGround);
        #endif
    });
});

return cell;
```

2nd :- Like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t fairCellBackGroundcallerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_queue_t fairCellBackGrounddownloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Thumb downloader", NULL);

dispatch_async(fairCellBackGrounddownloadQueue, ^
{
    UIImage *imageFairCellBackGround = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentFair FairCellBackGround]]]];

    dispatch_async(fairCellBackGroundcallerQueue, ^
    {
        cell.fairCellBackGround.image = imageFairCellBackGround;
    });
});
dispatch_release(fairCellBackGrounddownloadQueue);
```

But still it isn't solved.
Please if any one have any solution, share with me.
Thanks a lot, in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution of this particular problem.
Here it is:

```
    imageQueueFairLogo = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(imageQueueFairLogo, ^
    {
        UIImage *imageFairLogo = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentFair FairLogo]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            //[imageCache setObject:imageLogoCache forKey:currentFair.FairLogo];
            cell.fairLogoImageView.image = imageFairLogo;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
```

And of course "**Declare**" & "**@synthesize**" the corresponding dispatch queue in your "MyClass.h" & "MyClass.m" file like this :

```
    @property(nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t imageQueueFairLogo;
    @synthesize imageQueueFairLogo;
```

Do the same thing for "imageQueueFairCellBackGround"
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
if (postAndCheckInDetails.postImageURL.length != 0)
                {
                    if (!uploadImage)
                        uploadImage = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:4];

                    dispatch_queue_t checkInQueueForPostImage = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

                    dispatch_async(checkInQueueForPostImage, ^{
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postAndCheckInDetails.postImageURL]]];

                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            if (image!=nil) {
                                [uploadImage setImage:image];
                                [uploadImage setFrame:CGRectMake(80, checkInDateAndTime.frame.origin.y+40, 160, 120)];
                            }

                            [cell setNeedsLayout];
                        });
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I try it like you said :

I have to add cell, before "uploadImage" & commenting out 
"[uploadImage setFrame:CGRectMake(80, checkInDateAndTime.frame.origin.y+40, 160, 120)];"
Because it can't recognize "checkInDateAndTime"...

Thank you for your comment. :)
But, It still not working, after reset the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

comment out the lines with dispatch_retain and dispatch_release and add [cell setNeedsDisplay] after you have updated the image

Comment: I try like this, as you said :

    
`dispatch_queue_t imageQueueFairLogo = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(imageQueueFairLogo, ^
    {
        //dispatch_retain(imageQueueFairLogo);
        UIImage *imageFairLogo = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentFair FairLogo]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            cell.fairLogoImageView.image = imageFairLogo;
            [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });`

But, not working after reset the simulator.
Thanks for commenting. :)